# Provide multiple parameters with dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have this code:

```
public void SaveBoardgameCollection(BoardgameCollection boardgameCollection)
{
    if (boardgameCollection?.BoardgameUserStatusList.Count > 0)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_databaseConnectionString.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Execute("dbo.BoardgameCollectionInsert @BoardGameComment, @Own, @ForTrade, @Want, @WantToPlay, @WantToBuy, @WishList, @Grade, @GameId, @PreOrdered, @PrevOwned", boardgameCollection.BoardgameUserStatusList);
        }
    }
}
```

Say that the SP now demands another parameter that BoardgameUserStatusList objects does not contain. How can I provide this in the same Execute, for example a User Id(GUID)?

Edit:

If I do this:

```
queryParameters = new DynamicParameters();
queryParameters.Add("@MyParameter1", boardgameCollection.BoardgameUserStatusList);
queryParameters.Add("@MyParameter2", System.Guid.NewGuid());
//@BoardGameComment, @Own, @ForTrade, @Want, @WantToPlay, @WantToBuy, @WishList, @Grade, @GameId, @PreOrdered, @PrevOwned
connection.Execute("dbo.BoardgameCollectionInsert ", queryParameters);
```

I will get a NotSupportedException that says that the BoardgameUserStatus(object in BoardgameUserStatusList cannot be used as a parameter value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using a dynamic parameter? Here is a simple example.

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@MyParameter", value);
parameters.Add("@MySecondParameter", value2);

using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_databaseConnectionString.ConnectionString))
{
    db.ExecuteAsync("dbo.BoardgameCollectionClear", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

Comment: Note that this could be built dynamically by looping over some sort of collection that you may have.

Comment: I have cleaned up my code. I need to execute BoardgameCollectionInsert sp for each object in the boardgameCollection. The inparameter for the SP is matching the object in the boardgameCollection list. So far so good, it will run and add all of the records to the database. But what if I add a parameter, say userId to the SP. It is supose to be the same userId for all of them so how do I provide this userId as a parameter to the BoardgameCollectionInsert? I dont want to add it as a property on the ibject in the boardgameCollection list.

Comment: To use the dynamic parameters you have to set each parameter in the stored procedure, so you will have to loop through the list and add each property  to the coresponding parameter.